# Simple Application of Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I know that Heine-Borel Theorem states the following:

If $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $S$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Now I want to show the closed and bounded property of a closed interval $[0, 1]$. Here I have tried proving closedness by contradiction. I can make  use of the following: A set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open if for every element $x \in S$, there is an r > $0$ such that $B(x,r)$ is a subset of $S$.
Now suppose $[0, 1]$ is open and it contains $0$ as an  element. Then $B(0,r)$ contains $(0 - r)$ as an element which is not an element of $[0, 1]$ for $r >0$. Thus, $B(x,r)$ is not a subset of $S$. Contradiction. It should be closed.

Can you provide alternative proofs and comment on mine?

Second I want to check whether $\mathbb{R}_+$, the set of nonnegative real numbers, is closed and bounded. (I think $\mathbb{R}_+$ is closed but not bounded due to the upper bound which goes to positive infinity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the opposite of "open" is not "closed", showing a set is not open does not mean it is necessarily closed. If you want to show a set is closed, you need to show its complement is open.

So you should begin with $S^C=(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$, and for every $x\in S^C$, find a open ball around it that lies completely in $S^C$.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think I've heard what you stated called the Heine-Borel theorem. The names I am familiar with are Heine-Borel as "topologically compact is equivalent to sequentially compact" and Bolzano-Weierstrass as "sequentially compact is equivalent to closed and bounded".

For your first part, $[0,1]$ is bounded; it's bounded below by $0$ and above by $1$. It is closed because in the real numbers we have the property of preservation of nonstrict inequalities under limits. That is, if $x_n \to L$ and for every $n$, $x_n \leq x$, then $L \leq x$. Similarly if $x_n \geq x$ then $L \geq x$. You should prove this using the definition of limit. From this it follows that if $x_n \in [0,1]$ and $x_n \to L$ then $L \in [0,1]$, i.e. $[0,1]$ is closed.

For your second part, $\mathbb{R}_+$ is pretty easily seen to be not bounded.

Comment: if you search for "Heine-Borel" on the net, most if not all results point to the statement by the OP.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Interesting, my undergrad analysis book and a quick google search agree. I wonder why I remembered it the other way...